# How can I control the volume of media within a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, video, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView that will be used to load audio and/or video and I want the volume of media contained in the UIWebView to match that of my app.  How can I set the audio volume for a UIWebView?

Comment: I think its not possible, I hope you find an answer.. it's interesting!

Comment: What's the media source?

Comment: Advertisements.  I'm hoping there's a way to essentially control the volume of the entire UIWebView, since I won't know exactly what will be loaded into it.